# itextsharp SetFields not setting

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have my temp PDF on the network and am using asp to fill in the fields and then download the file.

The problem I have is that the file downloaded is just the blank template, none of the fields are filled?

My code

```
Dim doc As New Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate)
Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
Dim writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms)
writer.Open()

Dim PdfR As New PdfReader("http://192.168.0.221/template.pdf")
Dim PdfS As New PdfStamper(PdfR, ms)

Dim fields As AcroFields = PdfS.AcroFields
fields.SetField("s1", "00")
fields.SetField("pono", "100")
PdfS.FormFlattening = True
PdfS.Close()
PdfR.Close()


Dim r = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
r.ContentType = "application/pdf"
r.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=Testing.pdf", "Testing"))
r.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray)
```

Comment: You're doing two different things above which might not be breaking now but could some day in the future. `PdfWriter` is for creating brand new PDFs from scratch. `PdfStamper` is for working with already existing PDFs. These two should never be mixed. You should be able to throw away lines 1, 3 and 4 above.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I had done this after I posted on here as I noticed they were not doing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone else ever hits this issue

1) If you dont mind your fields being editable then remove the FormFlattening command
2) Else add this `fields.GenerateAppearances = True`

Comment: This worked for me, just call GenerateAppearances before setting the fields and FormFlattening afterwards.